# Problems with echo arguments into bash script

Tags: bash, variables, pipe

I'm having some problems with the following code:

```
echo XX.txt 4 | script
```

The script should write the 4th line of XX.txt, but I'm having trouble getting both echoed arguments into variables in the script. I have to use echo because it's a school exercise. :)

How can I get XX.txt and 4 as seperate variables in my script? I've tried using read, but it puts both arguments in only 1 variable.

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read` should work. You have to specify both variables to it, though:

```
echo XX.txt 4 | { read file num
                  echo File: $file
                  echo Num: $num
                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know I could get multiple variables with read! Thanks !